# Javascript check if div overlaps other div

Tags: javascript

I can't get my head around this problem, so i hope that you guys can help me fixing it.

The thing is that I want to check if an div is overlapping an another div when they are dynamically added to the body.

Let's say that I've got an first div with the following information:

[image]

```
X1 = 316, X2 = 440
```

This is being calculated with the information that an box has an length of `60px` and `1px` margin around him. Also, the `exL` stands for the amount of 'boxes' inside the div ( in this test case it's 2, but it will be many more... ) So the code to calculate that is:

```
var X2 = ( oldX1 + ( kist_length * exL ) + ( 2 * exL))
```

I've got this code so far:

```
// X:
oldX1 = ( 316 );
oldX2 = ( oldX1 + ( kist_length * exL ) + ( 2 * exL));
newX1 = ( 99 );
newX2 = ( newX1 + ( kist_length * newLength ) + ( 2 * newLength));
if( (newX1 >= oldX1 || newX1 <= oldX2) || ( newX2 >= oldX2 || newX2 <= oldX2) ){
    console.log("X is overlapping...");
}
```

If i use the code above the program says it's overlapping, but as you can see below, that's not true. the values that the checker is using are ( `+ kisten` stands for + the length ( so the boxes + length of box * times of boxes ):
[image]

```
newX = 99
newX + kisten = 223
oldX = 316
oldX + kisten = 440
```

I know that it's because the `OR` statement. But if I use `AND` statements between the `()` inside the if, it's not working 100% to. Let's take a look at the following picture:
[image]

First I've placed `Box1`. After that I've placed `Box2`, that succeeded without the warning about an overlapping. But `X` is overlapping...( not the `Y`, but the `X` is... ). When i place `Box3`, i do get the warning that `X` is overlapping...

So my question is rather simple ( but i guess the answer isn't... ), What do I wrong with the check? Which part of the if statement did i do wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess there is a typo in your script, since `newX2 >= oldX2 || newX2 <= oldX2` is always true :-)

But the condition in order to not have any overlapping is that (I reason on segments since you are dealing axis by axis here) new segment is before the old one :

```
      newX1----------------newX2        oldX1---------------oldX2
```

or the second one is after first one :

```
         oldX1---------------oldX2    newX1----------------newX2
```

So the corresponding condition is the following one :

```
function overlaps() {
    var minOldX = Math.min(oldX1, newX1),
        maxOldX = Math.max(oldX1, newX1),
        minNewX = Math.min(oldX2, newX2),
        maxNewX = Math.max(oldX2, newX2); 

    return (
        maxNewX <= minOldX || // <- first case
        minNewX >= maxOldX    // <- second case
    );
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for you answer. I think it will work, but when i implement it inside my code, it doesn't. The thing is that i do an loop over an array with coordinates, so I've made an if statement of the return ( `if( maxX2 <= minX1 || minX2 >= maxX1 ){ return false; }` ) but now it's always returning false ( even when it shouldn't, like when i place the boxes as in the second pic... ) Did i do something wrong with the if statement?

Comment: I think that you've made a little typo. The `maxX1` is with `newX1` also. Shouldn't that be `newX2`? Same for `maxX2`... I've changed that and now it's more working.. [Here's an pic of the situation now](http://i.imgur.com/13eMWld.png). The thing is that i now can't create an box between those 2, while it should be possible... Do you've got any idea what could be the problem?

Comment: Sorry, I have put `Math.min` everywhere (instead of `Math.min` and `Math.max`). But `minX1` is the smallest X coordinate on segment going from `oldX1` to `newX1`, and so on, so I think the other points are correct, isn't it?

Comment: Wow, now it's working indeed. Thank you so very much... Been working on this problem for days... And your right about the smallest coordinate, but because everything was `Math.min`, i thought that the values should be different. But now it shouldn't. So the answer you provided now is right. Thank you very much!

Comment: (Sorry I've been a bit confused by your notations -> I've adapted mine in order to adapts to yours)

Comment: Eeuhm, with `the answer you provided`, I meant this: `var minX1 = Math.min(oldX1, newX1), maxX1 = Math.max(oldX1, newX1), minX2 = Math.min(oldX2, newX2), maxX2 = Math.max(oldX2, newX2);`