# Check if one html element intersects another?

Tags: javascript

Basically I have 3 squares (3 `divs`) and I want to check if one of them intersects another.

[image]

I'm using the function.

```
document.getElementById("container1").getBoundingClientRect();
```

This is the output using this function

[image]

but I do not know how to verify if indeed one element intersects another.

For example, the pink border square intersects the blue border square and vice versa, while the red border div intersects none. Is there any way to verify this intersection?

```
<div class="container1" id="container1">

</div>
<div class="container2" id="container2">

</div>
<div class="container3" id="container3">

</div>

container1Rect = document.getElementById("container1").getBoundingClientRect();
container2Rect =document.getElementById("container2").getBoundingClientRect();
container3Rect = document.getElementById("container3").getBoundingClientRect();
```

This is my livecode:

https://jsfiddle.net/cyst0m71/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Determine if two rectangles overlap each other?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306316/determine-if-two-rectangles-overlap-each-other)

Comment: @Remeus I forgot to put my code (I updated my question), I do not have very clear the answer, you have supplied a code in c ++ I am not sure how to do it in javascript.

Comment: The accepted answer really works in any programming language, check it out.

Comment: THE REAL duplicate of [Javascript check if div overlaps other div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24135340/javascript-check-if-div-overlaps-other-div)

Comment: @RandyCasburn I appreciate the help, but I do not understand how to do it. in my case the positions are dynamic

Comment: So _now_ they are dynamic. Since you are lost, why don't you start easy and solve the "static" version that _THIS_ question asks about. Then when you have that part solved, come back and ask **a new question** about the dynamic part.

Comment: it has 4 coordinates, x,y,w,h

Comment: @Tom  https://jsfiddle.net/cyst0m71/1/ I am trying of use the code of version C++

Comment: @Remeus   https://jsfiddle.net/cyst0m71/1/ I am trying of use the code of version C++

Comment: The answer is based on standard Cartesian coordinates (x increases left to right, and Y increases bottom to top). In JS, Y increases bottom to top, so you need to flip the signs for top/bottom: `if (container3Rect.left < container2Rect.right && container3Rect.right > container2Rect.left && container3Rect.top < container2Rect.bottom && container3Rect.bottom > container2Rect.top)`

Comment: Never post images of code, errors or output! https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask